# How to obtain files from a directory path channel in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I basically have a process that outputs a directory, and then I want to pass all the files in that directory into blast, how can I do that?

The error is in how I am passing information throught the workflow, namely in the construction of ch_forBlast:

```
workflow {
    ...
    ch_consensus = CONSENSUS_BUILDING(ch_trimmed.fastq)
    ch_forBlast = Channel.fromPath("${ch_consensus.consensusDir}/*.fasta")
    ch_blast = BLAST(ch_forBlast, db_dir)
}
```

But I just get an empty file or nothing, I think I just don't understand very well how to go from a path channel to the files in it, and I haven't been able to find out how to do that. Any insight?

These are the relevant parts of the workflow...any suggestions appreciated. I edited a bit based on the very helpful comments from @dthorbur:

```
process CONSENSUS_BUILDING {
//THIS WORKS FINE
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/consensus", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path fastq

    output:
    path "${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID/*.fasta", emit: consensus_fastas

    script:
    """
    gunzip -f ${fastq}
    NGSpeciesID --ont --sample_size 10000 --consensus --racon --racon_iter 3 --fastq ${fastq.getSimpleName()}.fastq --m 650 --s 50 --outfolder ${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID
    """
}

process BLAST {
//THIS WORKS FINE IN ISOLATION
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/blast", mode: 'copy'
    container  'docker://ncbi/blast'

    input:
    path fasta
    path db

    output:
    path "${fasta.getParent()}_${fasta.getSimpleName()}.blast"

    script:
    """                                                                                                                            
    blastn -db $db/$db_name -query $fasta -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue b\
itscore' -out ${fasta.getParent()}_${fasta.getSimpleName()}.blast                                                                  
    """
}

// Overall workflow
workflow {
    ...
    ch_consensus = CONSENSUS_BUILDING(ch_trimmed.fastq)
    ch_forBlast = Channel.fromPath("${ch_consensus.consensusDir}/*.fasta")
    ch_blast = BLAST(CONSENSUS_BUILDING.out.consensus_fastas, db_dir)
}
```

But I am getting:

error [nextflow.exception.ProcessUnrecoverableException]: Process `BLAST (1)` script contains error(s)
Nov-17 11:01:12.310 [Actor Thread 9] ERROR nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Error executing process > 'BLAST (1)'

Caused by:
No signature of method: nextflow.util.BlankSeparatedList.getParent() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getTarget(), setTarget(java.util.List), getAt(int), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(java.lang.N
umber), getAt(groovy.lang.Range) -- Check script 'bleePipelineBlast.nf' at line: 114

Source block:
"""
blastn -db $db/$db_name -query $fasta -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart s
end evalue bitscore' -out ${fasta.getParent()}_${fasta.getSimpleName()}.blast
"""

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`
Nov-17 11:01:12.312 [Actor Thread 9] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session aborted -- Cause: Process `BLAST (1)` script conta
ins error(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the `nextflow.log` file, but my guess is the workflow initially tried to look in `"${ch_consensus.consensusDir}/*.fasta"` at the start of the workflow and finds nothing since there is nothing telling it to wait for `CONSENSUS_BUILDING` to finish.

I suspect you can fix this with a more appropriate output declaration. I'm unfamiliar with `NGSpeciesID`, but I'm going to assume the output is a directory with consensus fastas. You can adjust the process from there.

EDIT: Adjusting the script based on the comment from OP.

```
process CONSENSUS_BUILDING {
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/consensus", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path fastq

    output:
    path "${fastq.getSimpleName()}.fastq", emit: fastq // Are you emitting the same fastq you used as input? You can use queue channels multiple times with DSL2, so this may be unnecessary. 
    path "${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID/*.fasta", emit: consensus_fastas

    script:
    """
    gunzip -f ${fastq}
    NGSpeciesID --ont --sample_size 10000 --consensus --racon --racon_iter 3 --fastq ${fastq.getSimpleName()}.fastq --m 650 --s 50 --outfolder ${fastq.getSimpleName()}_ID
    """
}

process BLAST {
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/blast", mode: 'copy'
    container  'docker://ncbi/blast'

    input:
    tuple path(sampleID), path(fasta)
    path db

    output:
    path "${sampleID}.blast"

    script:
    """                                                                                                                            
    blastn -db $db/$db_name -query $fasta -outfmt '6 sseqid stitle pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send evalue b\
itscore' -out ${sampleID}.blast                                                                  
    """
}


workflow {
    ...
    CONSENSUS_BUILDING(ch_trimmed.fastq)
    CONSENSUS_BUILDING
      .out
      .consensus_fastas
      .map{ it -> tuple(it.simpleName, it) }
      .set{ blast_in }

    BLAST(blast_in , db_dir)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my answer to include what I got from .nextflow.log...it seems like it's passing empty things, but I have no clue why...

Comment: I hadn't realised you could apply groovy functions in the script box. Since the error seems to be linked to these commands, can to try adjusting the the channel with `map` before or conduct the  `getParent()`/`getSimpleName()` in bash instead?

I'll update my answer with an example I would try.